# How do I stop my character feeling like they're on ice using RigidBody2D Velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently using RB2D velocity for movement but I can't make it stop sliding after I've finished pressing the button. It feels like the Ice level from Mario. How do I stop my character sliding everywhere?

My code is:

```
void Movement() {

     if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0.1) {

         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

     }
     if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < -0.1) {

         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (-speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

     }
     if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > 0.5 && grounded) {

         GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, jumpHeight);

     }
}
```

My speed is set to 5, jumpHeight is 10 and I have both box collider and RigidBody2D on my player

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transform to move the object when pressing keys and directly move it without using the physics.

Also using the velocity, you can set it to 0.0f when you are not pressing any button to stop moving the object.

crabcrabcam is now using:

```
    void Movement() {

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0.1) {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

    } else if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < -0.1) {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (-speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

    } else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 0 && grounded) {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (Vector2.zero, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.y);

    }


    if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > 0.5 && grounded) {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x, jumpHeight);

    }

}
```

This makes it floaty in the air but whilst grounded it stops responsively :)

Comment: Do you mean use Transform.translate()? Because that causes characters to bug in and out of walls. I'll give the velocity a go though, thanks :)

Comment: The setting velocity worked thanks :). I'll just edit your answer with the code I'm using for any future people looking here :)

Comment: I was taking about moving the Transfor.position, but velocity its more acurrate for moving with physics.
Thanks for accepting the answer. And as a Programmer said, use Vector2.zero.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Add else if to the second if statement then another else statement you can use to stop moving the player.

```
if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.1)
{
Move right
}
else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.1)
{
Move left
}
else
{
Stop moving/Vector2.zero;
}
```

Maybe something like this:

```
void Movement()
{

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.1)
    {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    }
    else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.1)
    {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(-speed, GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);
    }
    else
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5 && grounded)
    {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x, jumpHeight);

    }
}
```

Comment: I got this just before you answered. My code is pretty much the same as this :) Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Just looked at your code in the Edit which is not visible yet(I approved it).Although, they are not the-same. No `Vector2.zero;` in your code, which you should use for an instant stop. Also, the last `else if` statement in your code should simply be `else` since you are only looking for 3 possible things(left, right, not pressed) if  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")`. Here is an easy code sample:

```
public float maxSpeed = 10f;
public float jumForce = 700f;
public Transform groundCheck;
float groundRadius = 0.2f;
public LayerMask whatIsGrounded;
bool grounded = false;


void FixedUpdate()
{
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGrounded)

    float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
}

void Update()
{
    if(grounded &&  Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }
}
```